# Escaping and Inserting Serialized Data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following data as an example:

```
$a = addslashes('hello\'s');
$b = serialize($a);

// As you know, $b looks like this s:8:"hello\'s";
```

Now when I insert $b to MySQL, the data now looks like this s:8:"hello's" inside MySQL.
MySQL removes the \ and now I have an invalid serialized data.

What's the best way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's an escape() function in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First serialize** the value you want **and then** use the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). That's the string you are going to put in the database after all. Try to avoid addslashes...

If you don't want to have an active connection at the time, try this function:

```
function mysql_escape_no_conn( $input ) { 

    if( is_array( $input ) ) {
        return array_map( __METHOD__, $input ); 
    }
    if( !empty( $input ) && is_string( $input ) ) { 
        return str_replace( array( '\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a" ), 
                            array( '\\\\', '\\0', '\\n', '\\r', "\\'", '\\"', '\\Z' ),
                            $input ); 
} 

return $input;
```

}

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() asks for a connection upfront, is there a way to use it before connecting to the database? I like to format my data first before I connect to the MySQL.

Comment: Edited my answer according to your needs, which, by the way, I don't approve of... :)

Comment: -1, Rolling your own mysql_real_escape_string is a **bad** bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

For escaping parameters to go into an SQL query **you do not** use addslashes, but `mysql_real_escape_string`.

**Example:**

```
<?php
  $param = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['param']);
  $query = "SELECT f1, f2 FROM atable WHERE f3 = '$param' ";
  // these single quotes here are essential !!   ^      ^ 
  // if you leave out the quotes you **will** suffer SQL-injection.
```

This is the correct way to escape SQL-parameters.
Or even better use PDO with prepared statements, then you don't have to escape at all.

Comment: addslashes are generaly to be avoided, in my opinion... +1

Comment: `use PDO, then you don't have to escape at all` - a misleading statement, unless you replace `PDO` with `prepared statements`.

Comment: It is better to use parametized query. With your solution, there is still a risk (low, but present) of SQL injection.

Comment: @JMichelB, please give an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_real_escape_string` function!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the string in `$b` by using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

```
$a = addslashes('hello\'s');  
$b = serialize($a);  
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `field`='".mysql_real_escape_string($b)."'" ;
```

You should always escape input into a db to stop SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `mysql_real_escape_string()` should be called!

I just wanted to add that I always find it safe to `base64_encode()` all serialized arrays/objects I store in a database.  All you then have to do is call `base64_decode()` upon retrieval of the stored value.  I do this because `;` and other characters are liable to cause "Warning: Error at offset..." errors.