# Cannot insert when word contains single quotes

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add single quotes word like "Dwi'q" and "Jum'at" in PHP MYSQL,
but I cant add that word, I try search anything but I dont found it.

my query is:

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pln`(`ppno`,`persno`,`pernum`,`psgrup`,`lv`,`pos`,`nppsimkp`,`persub`,`busrea`,`pdthr`,`gk`,`marstakey`,`bkey`,`bakun`,`numtd`,`email`,`bdate`) VALUES ('".$ppno."','".$persno."','".$pernum."','".$psgrup."','".$lv."','".$pos."','".$nppsimkp."','".$persub."','".$busrea."','".$pdthr."','".$gk."','".$marstakey."','".$bkey."','".$bakun."','".$numtd."','".$email."','".$bdate."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: use mysqli_real_escape_string or mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php - this is a form of "accidental" SQL injection. The *best* way to fix it is to **stop using mysql_\* functions** and use either `mysqli` or PDO with *placeholders* (aka prepared statements). See the linked question.

Comment: Escape the quotes in your variables before passing them in query, check this thread, its the exact thing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887036/insert-a-value-containg-single-quotes-in-mysql

Comment: another => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028556/escaping-and-inserting-serialized-data-to-mysql ...wonder what have u searched!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert values with `'` you need to use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) or [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string). Also it better to use always when you are inserting values into DB in order to avoid SQL Injection.

And one more thing Please stop using `mysql_*` functions and start using `mysqli_*` function or `PDO`

**Example**

Using `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
$a = "some one's text";
$a = mysql_real_escape_string($a);
```

Using `mysqli_real_escape_string`

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","dbusername","dbpassword","dbname");
$a = "some one's text";
$a = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$a);
```

Comment: I would not recommend such outdated approaches, especially when there are *so many duplicates*. My recommendation is to *update* to mysqli (or PDO) and use *placeholders*.

Comment: Yes correct. But we dont know what php version he using. so we can give the option and tell him which is better one.

Comment: Any version of PHP that does not support a proper SQL client library should not be used.

Comment: agreed...this answer looks kind of obsolete...plus this is clear example of repetition of efforts for answering when similar threads exist!!!

Comment: Like it matters.. I could have added the same comment to every other answer. The mind-swarm for "escaping" is too strong :(

Answer (score 0):

In simple.. you can escape it with backslash..

```
$search_keyword="jum\'at";
```

but i recommend you to first sanitize the value before passing it into query.. using php function called

```
mysql_real_escape_string($search_keyword)
```

for ex;

```
$search_keyword=mysql_real_escape_string("jum'at");
```

Answer (score 0):

first do this:

```
$a = mysql_real_escape_string("Dwi'q");
$b = mysql_real_escape_string("Jum'at");
```

and then run your query providing these variables in your query.

Comment: $a and $b , i am talking about these variables

Comment: yes my mistake actully just typing mistake ,, thnks